# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: antlr/collections/AST when setting configurations.all.transitive = false

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, antlr

I am using gradle to build a fat jar with dependencies.  The original fat jar was 75MB.  I was able to reduce the size to 10MB by setting the following:

```
configurations.all {
    transitive = false
}
```

However, now when I run a gradle build, I get a new error:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':service-common:metrics:checkstyleMain'.
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: antlr/collections/AST
```

Here is my new build script:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins:shadow:5.2.0"
        classpath "org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:latest.release"
    }
}
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'maven-publish'
}
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'antlr'

checkstyleMain.exclude '**/**Test.java'
build_docker.enabled = false

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven {
        url = 'https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/'
    }
    mavenCentral()
}

configurations.all {
    transitive = false
}

dependencies {
    antlr "org.antlr:antlr4:4.7.1"
    runtime "org.antlr4:antlr4-runtime:4.7.1"
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.6'
    implementation (
        'io.micrometer:micrometer-core:1.6.4',
        'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.5',
        'org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.7.5',
        'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.12.1'
    )
    compile (
        'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.10.4',
        'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.10.4',
        'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.10.4',
        'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.8.1',
        'org.json:json:20180813',
        'com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml:2.10.0',
        'com.google.guava:guava:19.0',
        'org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:2.4.1',
        'org.yaml:snakeyaml:1.2+',
        'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:2.12.1',
        'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.12.1',
        'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.12.1'
    )
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.6'
    testImplementation (
        'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.22.0',
        'junit:junit:4.12',
        'org.assertj:assertj-core:3.19.0',
        'org.mockito:mockito-all:1.10.19',
        'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.2',
        'net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:1.10.20'
    )
}
```

As you can see, I have tried to enable the antltr plugin directly.  But I still get the class not found error.  Am I missing something?

Comment: My guess would be that `org.antlr:antlr4:4.7.1` in the antlr configuration requires it's transitive dependency `antlr4-runtime`, and you've told the build to drop it

Answer (score 0):

I found out the answer.  I had to run

```
gradle dependencies
```

To see which libs were needed to checkstyle.  I manually added those libs and it worked.